# Create a RealmQuery on background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm

I am trying to implement a DBService class, which runs on the background thread, that has a method Observable getWhere(@NonNull RealmQuery realmQuery). As i know that i need to create the Realm instance on the same thread i access it. So, i found a way to create the RealmQuery on the background thread, but its a horrible hack. All my other attempts resulted in `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created`

Presenter Code :

```
dataUseCase.searchDisk(getRealmQuery(RepoRealm.class)
                .equalTo("owner.login", userLogin), RepoRealm.class)


public static getRealmQuery RealmQuery(Class clazz) { // horrible hack
    if (handler == null)
        handler = new Handler(getHandlerThread().getLooper());
    handler.postAtFrontOfQueue(() -> realmQuery = RealmQuery.createQuery(Realm.getDefaultInstance(), clazz));
    while (true) if (realmQuery != null) break;
    return realmQuery;
}
```

getHandlerThread().getLooper() returns my only background thread.

DBService :

```
public Observable<List> getWhere(@NonNull RealmQuery realmQuery) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return realmQuery.findAll().asObservable()
                .filter(results -> ((RealmResults) results).isLoaded())
                .map(o -> realm.copyFromRealm((RealmResults) o))
                .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> closeRealm(realm));
    });
}
```

I tried other approaches but i always receive the exception of Realm access from incorrect thread.

Although my solution works but, it can freeze my app for a while until the realmQuery is created, which what i would like to avoid. Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, don't use `handler.postAtFrontOfQueue)` and throw random Realm-managed objects across threads, especially if you're using RxJava which already has `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` which pretty much does the exact same thing

Comment: P.S. you're opening a new Realm instance that you never close

Comment: In order to answer this question, it is required to know **what exactly you do with `RealmResults<T>` you obtain from Realm**.

Comment: `i just want to create a realm instance on my background thread and pass it to the main thread to create a realm query` you cannot pass a Realm instance between threads. It's in the documentation.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the implementation of the DBService method. Am I still not closing that realm instance ?

Comment: I want my DBService to be a black box that i can get any data out of it. So, to pass complex queries, thats what i came up with. Do you have better suggestions ?

Comment: `handler.postAtFrontOfQueue(() -> realmQuery = RealmQuery.createQuery(Realm.getDefaultInstance(), clazz));` this method is the problematic one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public <T extends RealmModel> Observable<List<T>> getWhere(RealmQueryProvider<T> queryFactory) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return queryFactory.create(realm).asObservable()
                .filter(results -> ((RealmResults<T>) results).isLoaded())
                .map(o -> realm.copyFromRealm((RealmResults<T>) o))
                .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> closeRealm(realm));
    });
}

public interface RealmQueryProvider<T extends RealmModel> {
    RealmResults<T> create(Realm realm);
}

// example
Observable<List<Dog>> dogs = dbService.getWhere((realm) -> realm.where(Dog.class).findAll());
```

Comment: This code does not compile. queryFactory.create(realm).asObservable()
create(realm) does not have asObservable as method

Comment: Should have been results as indicated by my example

Comment: Yea i figured that out. I was trying it and it works. But i am facing a performance problem. its freezing my my UIThread, but I'm still checking if its something else

Comment: I assume it is something else. Unless your GC is running haywire

Comment: Out of curiosity, what scheduler is this on?

Comment: I am using this AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper())